# Why is React Interact JS intergration not updating correctly?

Tags: reactjs, interactjs

I am trying to integrate InteractJS and ReactJS and I am seeing a strange but predictable problem on moving items from one dropzone to another and a mismatch between the UI and the underlying state object array. I realise this is most likely a bug in my code due my limited knowledge or React updates and/or InteractJS events - or both - but after three days staring at it I am very grateful for any insight into what may be causing this problem.

I have created a minimal [codesandbox to demonstrate the problem](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-interactjs-dragdrop-fcyb1r?file=/src/group-dnd.js).

I can drag all of the items into a dropzone and between dropzones in reverse order and both state and rendered output correctly updates.

However if I drag an intermediate item (i.e. not the last one) from a dropzone into another, React incorrectly re-renders the object immediately succeeding the dragged item in the wrong dropzone.

My question is: Why does the React render not match the state object for intermediate items but works correctly dragging items in reverse order?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe it is because interactjs is messing directly with the DOM which is not good for reactjs since react uses virtual DOM. There is a package reactablejs which is a react HOC for interactjs.  Try and see if the issue still persists

Answer (score -1):

While researching how to handle multitouch gestures (drag and drop, zoom rotating, etc. of elements) in React.js I first found interactjs. It didn't worked well and after some more research I found [enter link description here](https://use-gesture.netlify.app/). Good documentation and it works very well with animation libraries.

I would strongly recommend not to use interactjs in a React project.

Comment: thanks for advice but this does not answer the question. Interact.js is a very flexible library and this post is about specific integration with React.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).